# Depth of an expression using Python

Tags: python-2.7

How do I find out the depth of an expression in python? The code I've written works well for inputs like `[[1,2],[1,2,[3,6,54]]` but not for ones like `depth (['+', ['expt', 'x', 2], ['expt', 'y', 2]]) => 2` and `depth(('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2), 1), ('/', 5, 2)))) => 4`

```
a=0
k=0
j=0
maxli=[] 
li =[[1,2],[1,2,[3,6,54]] # list whose depth is to be found
#print len(li)

def depth(x):


    global a,k,j
    j=j+1
    print" j's value is ",j
    for i in x:

      for h in range(len(li)): # runs loop through the items of the list 
          if i== li[h]  : k=0  

      if isinstance(i,(tuple,list)) == True: #if we find that there is list
        k=k+1

      #  print "this is for item",i  
      #  print k
        depth(i) 

    a=k
    maxli.append(a) # putting the values of a in maxli

depth(li)
print "The depth of tree is :",max(maxli)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting "deepness" or the deepest level a nested list goes to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039103/counting-deepness-or-the-deepest-level-a-nested-list-goes-to)

Comment: In my code i had depth in place of fn,i forgot to edit it before posting here..

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to utilize recursion here is via the return value of the function, not by manipulating global variables. You could define a depth function like this:

```
def is_list(x):
    return hasattr(x,'__getitem__') and type(x) != str

def depth(l):
    if not is_list(l): return 0
    maxdepth = 0
    for elem in l:
        maxdepth = max(maxdepth, depth(elem))
    return maxdepth + 1
```

Comment: As it turns out, it does use recursion. What was `fn` in the original post was meant to be `depth`, the name of the function.