# How many times can an array be flatten?

Tags: arrays

For example: if I have a 2d array

```
arr = [[1,2], [4,5], [7,5], 8]
```

the output should be 1, since it can be flatten once.
If I have a 1d array

```
arr = [1,3,4]
```

the output should be 0 since it can't be flatten.

What function should I use?

Comment: One you write yourself... What if the list has different nesting levels, e.g. `[1,[2,[3,4],5],6]`.

Comment: and what is max depth of your input array?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if that's the case, follow the highest nesting level

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest maybe 3 or 4

Comment: @JimmyLiao: can you show your own attempt?

Comment: There's no built-in function to do this. You'll need to write one. Try it, and if you get stuck show your attempt and we can help then.

Comment: Why does it matter? You can have a recursive "flattener" that flattens any nested level in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recursion:

```
def depth(arr):
    if isinstance(arr, list):
        return 1 + max(depth(elem) for elem in arr)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: The depth of a simple list should be `0`, and furthermore please do not make someones homework.

Comment: Might be a good idea to cite your [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039153/7954504) @PacoH

Comment: I actually wrote it myself, but I can see how you could come to that conclusion.